# is there a way to get the ip address of a forwarded machine from http request header in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, .net, api, model-view-controller

I have two LANs(for examle:A,B) that are connected using a Mikro Tik Router and my web application is hosted on **B**,when users from **A** send request to **B** the **IP Address** of all of them are same(ip address of router).
i can't get the ip address of **forwarded** machine.
I tried these lines of code but not worked:
`HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;`
`HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"]`

Is there any other way?

Comment: Is the header present in the request? Is the machine doing the forwarding a HA proxy?

Comment: yes the header presents in the request but the ip address of all forwarded machine are same.

Comment: Then that points to a problem with the machine doing the forwarding, doesn't it?

Comment: i can't find "X-Forwarded-For" key on my request header.Do I need to do anything to add "X-Forwarded-For" key?

Comment: On ASP.NET _Core_ you have to allow it and configure the source proxy. I'm not 100% sure about ASP.NET though.

Comment: Ok,Thank you for your comments and guidance.